# aggregateRating within Review object

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

We're trying to use the `aggregateRating` tag but we're getting this warning in the [SDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool):

> The `aggregateRating` property inside a `Review` object applies to the review itself, as a creative work. Did you mean to use `reviewRating` instead.

We want to aggregate the reviews from all users, not use `reviewRating` (we already use that one for our own reviews).

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

JSON-LD ([example page](https://dev.commonsensemedia.org/movie-reviews/it/user-reviews/adult)):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Review",
    "name": "It",
    "datePublished": "2017-09-06",
    "description": "Based on Stephen King's 1986 novel, […]",
    "url": "https://dev.commonsensemedia.org/movie-reviews/it",
    "reviewBody": "Based on Stephen King's 1986 novel, […]",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Jeffrey M. Anderson",
        "sameAs": "https://dev.commonsensemedia.org/users/jeffrey-m-anderson"
    },
    "itemReviewed": {
        "@type": "Movie",
        "name": "It",
        "sameAs": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1396484/",
        "datePublished": "2017-09-08",
        "image": {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "image.jpg"
        },
        "director": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Andres Muschietti"
        },
        "actor": [
            {
                "@type": "Person",
                "name": "Bill Skarsg\u00e5rd"
            },
            {
                "@type": "Person",
                "name": "Jaeden Lieberher"
            },
            {
                "@type": "Person",
                "name": "Finn Wolfhard"
            }
        ]
    },
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Common Sense Media",
        "sameAs": "https://www.commonsensemedia.org"
    },
    "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "ratingValue": "4"
    },
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4.04651",
        "bestRating": 5,
        "worstRating": 1,
        "reviewCount": "43",
        "name": "Parents say",
        "description": "All parent member reviews for It"
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include a minimal markup example that a) shows what you have/want and b) gives the quoted error (in Google’s SDTT, I assume?).

Comment: @unor I have no idea what you're saying but I added an example and you can see the warning if you put it in the testing tool.

Comment: You should always include the (minimal) markup in the question instead of linking to it, so that the question keeps being useful for others even if your page changes or is deleted. I included the JSON-LD from the example page (and shortened the longer text values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the [`aggregateRating`](http://schema.org/aggregateRating) property to the [`Review`](http://schema.org/Review) item, the aggregated rating is for the review, not for the reviewed item.

If the aggregated rating is for the reviewed item, you have to add the `aggregateRating` to this item (e.g., `Movie`).

If that is what you want, you can move the `aggregateRating` under `Movie`, e.g.:

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Review",

    "itemReviewed": {
        "@type": "Movie",

        "aggregateRating": {
          "@type": "AggregateRating"
        }

    }
}
```